# Heine-Borel: why must an infinite subset have a limit point?

Tags: real-analysis

Or perhaps the more general form of the theorem I'm thinking about is: let $K$ be a compact set, let $E$ be an infinite subset of $K$. Then $E$ must have a limit point in $K$. This question seems to assume that $E$ even has a limit point. Once I accept that $E$ must have at least one limit point, then I understand the proof for why at least one limit point is in $K$. But what about $E$ in this case is so special to guarantee that it must have at least one limit point? Is it the fact that $K$ is compact, and that $E$ is inside a compact set? Because I can think of a generic infinite subset without any limit points.

For example, just take the set of all discrete integers as separate points, clearly there are no limit points. However, obviously this set will not be bounded. And compact $K$ is bounded so since $E$ is subset of $K$, $E$ must also be bounded. So this proposed counter-example fails.

What about the nature of $E$? Can this infinite subset $E$ be open or closed, or neither?

Comment: By the way if you assume a topological space $X$ is $T_1$ then $X$ is countably compact if and only if every infinite subset has a limit point..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is because $K$ is compact and because $E\subset K$. And, no, you don't have to assume from the start that $E$ has some limit point. The theorem says that it has a lmit point and thet it blongs to $K$.

To see why, suppose otherwise. That is, suppose that no point of $K$ is a limit point of $E$. Then each $x\in K$ will have an open neighborhood $N_x$ with only finitely many elements of $E$. But then $\{N_x\,|\,x\in K\}$ is an open cover of $K$, and therefore it has a finite subcover $\{N_{x_1},N_{x_2},\ldots,N_{x_N}\}$. But $E\subset\bigcup_{l=1}^NN_{x_k}$ and therefore $E$ would be a finite set.

Answer (score 0):

That is very interesting and the proof is almost a copy of the Heine Borel theorem. The nested intervals method works just fine.

The infinite set E could be open because it's limit point does not have to be in E.

Answer (score 0):

I find it instructive to consider a concrete example:

Suppose $K = [0, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ is the closed unit interval, a compact subset of the real numbers, and suppose that $E \subset K$ is infinite. Repeatedly cut $K$ in half, and, after each bisection, pick the left half if it contains infinitely elements of $E$, and the right half otherwise.

Since $E$ contains infinitely many elements, each of these sub-intervals must be nonempty. Moreover, by associating a $0$ with left half choices and a $1$ with right half choices, we are specifying the limit point by producing its binary representation. Our sequence of points is contained in $E \subset K$, and this sequence has a limit point by construction; since $K$ is compact, the limit point is contained in $K$.

Of course, the limit point need not be contained in $E$; for example, consider the set of reciprocals of the natural numbers, which yields the unique limit point $0 \not\in E$ (but, as desired, $0 \in K$).